# Incomplete row set returned when joining table to itself

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am attempting to use a query to retrieve details for the most recent backup for each of the databases on a server.

Query is:

```
WITH CTE_max as 
( 
  SELECT bs2.database_name,MAX(bs2.backup_start_date) as maxdate 
  FROM msdb.dbo.backupset bs2 GROUP BY database_name
)

SELECT DISTINCT
    CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
    bs1.database_name,
    bs1.backup_start_date,
    bs1.backup_finish_date,
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset bs1 
    INNER JOIN CTE_max CTE ON bs1.backup_start_date = CTE.maxdate
ORDER BY 
    bs1.database_name, 
    bs1.backup_start_date desc
```

When I run this, it only returns the details for about half of the databases on the server. I have tried replacing the CTE with a subquery in the main query and also casting the dates to varchars before joining them but the results are the same.

When I run the CTE query on its own it returns results all of the databases but as soon as it's joined in the main query about half the results disappear. I'm somewhat perplexed as to how this is possible as the table is being joined to itself.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should do the join on database_name as well. I wouldn't be surprised if the `distinct` is messing the result set up.

Comment: @ HoneyBadger. Thanks, just tried that but the results remain the same.

Comment: Do you have sample data? Ideally with records selected in the CTE which are not in the result set.

Comment: @ HoneyBadger. I just pasted the same code into a new query window to remove some of the company specific info in the query and re-ran it, and now it is working. I can only assume there was some SSMS wierdness going on! Thanks

Comment: Your welcome, glad your problem is resolved.

Comment: @Blimbeard: If your query returned half records after including database name in join and removing DISTINCT, it is most likely because backup_start_date for some of the records was NULL. Handling NULL or replacing INNER JOIN by LEFT JOIN might have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, Add DBName in your join condition better post some sample data for testing.

```
WITH CTE_max as 
( 
  SELECT bs2.database_name,MAX(bs2.backup_start_date) as maxdate 
  FROM msdb.dbo.backupset bs2 GROUP BY database_name
)

SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(100), SERVERPROPERTY('Servername')) AS Server, 
    bs1.database_name,
    bs1.backup_start_date,
    bs1.backup_finish_date
FROM msdb.dbo.backupset bs1 
    INNER JOIN CTE_max CTE ON bs1.backup_start_date = CTE.maxdate
    AND bs1.database_name=CTE.database_name
ORDER BY 
    bs1.database_name, 
    bs1.backup_start_date desc
```